# Dynamic Class Properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do you make a class property that recalculates each time you use it?

```
class myClass {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.percent = x/y * 100
  }
}

var test = new myClass(5, 10)

test.percent
//50

test.x = 10
test.percent
//still 50
```

I want `test.percent` to change 100 and adapt to other changes.
Can I do this without turning the variable into a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a `getter`. A getter is recomputed everytime its property is accessed:

```js
class myClass {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }

  get percent(){
    return this.x / this.y * 100
  }
}

var test = new myClass(5, 10)

console.log(test.percent) //50

test.x = 10
console.log(test.percent) //100
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this

1. You can have `this.percent` as a function

```js
class myClass {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y
    this.percent = function() {
      return this.x / this.y * 100
    }
  }
}
var test = new myClass(5, 10)

console.log(test.percent())
test.x = 10
console.log(test.percent())
```

---

2. You can also use `getter`

```js
class myClass {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  get percent() {
    return this.x / this.y * 100
  }
}

var test = new myClass(5, 10)

console.log(test.percent)
test.x = 10
console.log(test.percent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an accessor ( `getter` ) to alter the data each time you are accessing it.

In your case, you can replace the percent property by a getter.

```js
class myClass {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }
  
  get percent() {
      return this.x / this.y * 100;
  }
}

var test = new myClass(5, 10)

console.log(test.percent);
//50

test.x = 10
console.log(test.percent);
//now 100
```

I have also edited your code to use `this` to access `x` and `y`